# Require a login and password for writing in the FileZilla server, but not in the reading

Tags: ftp, filezilla, ftp-server

I'm working on a android application that writes, in some parts, in a FileZilla server. In my code, I provide the login and password for the FileZilla so that the client could send some pictures and videos to it.

The client later on needs to read the FTP content (Display it), but for that purpose, he needs to enter the login and password, which I can't provide him otherwise he could write whatever he wants in my server.

Is there any way to require a login and password for writing in the FTP server, but not in the reading ??

Comment: Is the android application a kind of FTP client? Does your client use the application only for the sending part or also for the reading part?

Comment: I uses the Android application only to send data from the mobile to the serer. The reading process is done elsewhere.

Comment: And is the user entering username/password in your application or are these kind of hard-coded?

Comment: For the reading part, the login password are not hard coded. The user needs to enter them himself.

Comment: I was asking for application-part, so for the sending part. If I understand it correctly.

Comment: In the sending part, no problem, because they are hard coded right! The client doesn't get to see them.

Comment: Ok, see an update to my answer with some security hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup two accounts on the server. One with read-only access, and one with write access. Provide the client with password to read-only account. Or you can allow even anonymous read-only access to the server.

EDIT: Also, be aware that it would not be a problem for a hacker to retrieve the hard-coded password from your Android application binary. Make sure you restrict the area, where the account can write to, ideally to a single folder only. You should also set disk quota for the account, so that the hacker cannot fill your server's disk. And you should definitelly monitor the writable folder for an unusual activity.

Comment: Mr Martin!! Thanks you! I tried to create another user with read only access. I opened the app where I read the FTP data using this user, and it worked ! Thank you

Comment: Can I bother you again Martin ?? Is there a way to read from the FTP without having an account. I need to put some of the pictures in a website, and the users are not supposes to know the users I have in my FileZilla and enter login and pass each time they open it !!

Comment: Well, if you have the pictures on the website, why the users don't get them from there (HTTP), rather than from FTP?

Comment: no!! The pictures are stored in an FTP server. In the website, I just display from their FTP Url ! I actually tried to create a user anonymous without a password, and it doesn't ask me for any authentication! Is it proper ?